# Given a set of labels and x and y coordinates, how do I output the first 6 nearest neighbors for all labels in Python?

Tags: python

The dataset that I have is structured as below.

```
Label     x-coordinate    y-coordinate
  a           5               4
  b           6               7
  .
  .
  .
  aa          5               11
  ab          3               12
  .
  .
  .
  zz          12              13
```

I need to output a data frame that has the top 6 nearest neighbors (based on coordinate distance) as columns with the initial label name.

For example

```
Label  First   Second  Third  Fourth  Fifth  Sixth
  a      b       ab      ac     ad      ae     af
  b      c       ac      ad     ae      af     ag
  .
  .
  .
  zz
```

I know how to calculate the coordinate distance for a point with the remaining points, but not store how to store them in the way shown above.

I'd appreciate a hint and then I can go from there. Thanks.

**Edit 1: Made the output more clear.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per label, you would have to calculate the distance of each point from your label.
Assuming you have implemented a distance() function -

```
for label in points:
    distances = []
    for remaining_point in points:
        distances.append (distance(label, remaining_point))
    distances.sort()
    print (distances[1:7]) // As the point matching itself would have a distance of zero.
```

Comment: This would just output the top 6 for Label a right? I'm sorry, I've now edited the question.

Comment: No, this would give the output for every label.
We have run two loops - one to cycle through the label, and one for each label to cycle through the remaining points.

Since our first loop cycles through all the labels, we should get the output for every label.

Comment: Got it. I'm facing two issues. First, the top distances are printed for every row(label) and the first column is not label of that row. Second, I'm getting the top 6 distances and not the labels corresponding to them. How do I fix it? I'm really new to Python. I know these are noobie questions. :)